# Convert custom footnote environment with "environ" to endnotes

Tags: environments, footnotes, endnotes

To convert footnotes to endnotes, I know I can use the `endnotes` package with the commands shown below. Because I often have long footnotes I have created a custom environment for them using the `environ` package.

I can't figure out how to convert this environment for endnotes. TeX gives the error that `\BODY` is not defined.

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                        

% Dummy text                                                                                   
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}                                                                     

% Define a real environment for footnotes                                                      
% But how to convert to endnotes?                                                              
\usepackage{environ}                                                                           
\NewEnviron{Footnote}{\footnote{\BODY}}                                                        

% Convert footnotes to endnotes                                                                
\usepackage{endnotes}                                                                          
\let\footnote=\endnote                                                                         
\AtEndDocument{\theendnotes}                                                                   

\begin{document}                                                                               

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}                                                                

\lipsum[3]%                                                                                    
  \begin{Footnote} % Works normally, but not with endnotes conversion                                                                             
  \lipsum[4]                                                                                   

  \lipsum[5]                                                                                   
  \end{Footnote}                                                                               

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\NewEnviron{Footnote}{\expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\BODY}}` work?

Comment: The error message tells that obviously the macro `\BODY` is written to the `ent` file. However, `\BODY` is only defined within the `Footnote` environment (or any other of `environ`'s environments). The real endnote is the first expansion of `\BODY`. Hence my idea…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what happens with a standard `\endnote` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}

\newcommand{\foo}{foo} % just for the test

\begin{document}

Some text.\endnote{With a \foo{} explanation.}

\end{document}
```

After processing this document, you'll find a file with extension `.ent` containing

```
\@doanenote {1}
macro:->With
a
\foo
{}
explanation.
\@endanenote
```

You see that no macro expansion has taken place. So with your code, what's written with the test file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{Footnote}{\footnote{\BODY}}[] % no \ignorespacesafterend
\let\footnote\endnote

\newcommand{\foo}{foo} % just for the test

\begin{document}

Some text.
\begin{Footnote}
With a \foo{} explanation.
\end{Footnote}

\end{document}
```

in the `.ent` file is

```
\@doanenote {1}
macro:->\BODY

\@endanenote
```

Any `Footnote` environment would write `\BODY`, which however is not defined outside `Footnote` (it is loaded with the current environment's content and then forgotten) and it would be useless to define it anyway.

You need to expand `\BODY` before it's seen by `\endnote`:

```
\NewEnviron{Footnote}{\expandafter\footnote\expandafter{\BODY}}
```

so `\endnote` will act on the *expansion* of `\BODY` (that is, the environment's contents).

**Technical note.** Basically, `\endnote{Text}` does

```
\def\temp{Text}\immediate\write\endnotefile{\meaning\temp}
```

with some more inessential tricks for adding `\@doanenote{<note number>}` at the beginning and `\@endanenote` at the end and for splitting the footnote text across multiple lines.

Comment: I've since discovered that the definition of `Footnote` needs to end with a space, otherwise there will be no space after the footnote mark in the body text.

Comment: @AndrewCashner No, that's not correct; if you don't want the following space to be ignored, add `[]` at the end of the code for `Footnote`: `\NewEnviron{Footnote}{\footnote{\BODY}}[]`